# Error: referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Genexus

Tags: genexus

La situación es la siguiente.

Tengo dentro de una condición el llenado de un *SDT*, pero quiero limpiar una variable de decisión y marca el siguiente error:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

El código es el siguiente:

```
if &ban = 2     
            if &kar_anio2 = &anterior
                if &kar_periodo2 = &mes_anterior
                    if &esObservacion = "SI"
                        &sdtCeldaItem.pperiodo_anio = &kar_anio2
                        &sdtCeldaItem.numCeldas = 1
                        &sdtCeldaItem.pperiodo_num = &periodo_num
                        &sdtCeldaItem.mperiodo_nom = &kar_periodo2
                        &sdtCeldas.Add(&sdtCeldaItem)
                        &sdtCeldaItem= new SDTCeldasCombinar.SDTCeldas()
                        &anterior = &kar_anio2
                        &mes_anterior = &kar_periodo2
                        &esObservacion = "NO"
                    endif
                endif
            endif
        endif
```

La variable a la que quiero asignarle un valor es la  que se llama `&esObservacion`.

Comment: Bienvenid@! Te invito a pasar por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que también te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta. Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Por cierto, intenta darle formato al código para que sea legible.

Comment: [Acá](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) te dice cómo darle formato a tu pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, podría aclarar de que tipo de objeto se trata y que parámetros recibe ? Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el error puede venir por querer asignar propiedades de `&sdtCeldaItem` sin haberlo inicializado anteriormente.

Intenta mover la línea `&sdtCeldaItem= new SDTCeldasCombinar.SDTCeldas()` antes de la primera asignación, en este caso: `&sdtCeldaItem.pperiodo_anio = &kar_anio2`